# Access VBA using SQL for importing multiple tables and then ensuring that they are union

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Okay I am getting stuck with my code.
What I am trying to do is use specific data from multiple tables, but I want to use basically the `UNION ALL` and `INNER JOIN` functions, however, this is not supported with the Visual Basic of Access and I require it to go to a table so that I can proceed to my next step.
The whole interface work from a form that has buttons to press for normal users, basically setting up a whole interface for importing the reports.

My original import followed the advise that I received from here for the tables:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Clicks Returns] " & _
        "(SKU, [Item Description], [Jan 2016 FIN YTD TY % Returns]) " & _
        "SELECT Sku, [Item Description], [Jan 2016 FIN YTD TY % Returns] FROM [Jan 2016 Clicks Returns];"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

This works perfectly for appending the data to one table, however when importing the data from multiple tables into one table it follows this pattern:

[Result Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMQOQ.png)

However, I require this to be the result:

[Required Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QUuZ.png)

The issue is that Both SKU numbers would be similar and the Item Desc. would be the same.

And with the normal append method it just keep duplicating and I want it to follow a join type action, and I do not know how to approach this exactly with Visual Basics on Access.

Thank you for taking the time to review this and also providing assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with getting the information from the second table, you require the table to be updated. (so insert into won't work for the second time you need to get data...)

I would however reconsider your data structure, to have 1 data column in the table, and have 1 column indicating which month. Then when reporting you can pivot that information...

so basically this table format:
1) SKU
2) Item Description
3) Month
4) Month YTD information.

In the case above, your insert into will much more easily work, and you won't need an update statement.

I hope this helps.

Kind regards,

Comment: Hey AlexT82 thanks for the response to my question... lol I completely forgot of the update string I feel like kinda stupid now lol I'm going to try that out now... I like the advise you gave and it could work better actually... though I will have to do it on a separate one to test it out first, but I think it might be best to reconsider it according to your suggestion... I'll give some feedback soon on both subjects :)

Comment: Pleasure Heartless. Don't forget the upvote :). Let me know if you another question on this. regards,

Comment: I tried to up vote... but it say I require 15 score to up vote I wanted to earlier already...

Comment: Okay I was able to get this correct... Hmm quick question do you perhaps have a solution for using it to include like new SKU numbers cause currently it only import if the SKU is available... I tried using: 'code'    strSQL = "UPDATE [Clicks Returns] as c " & _
        "INNER JOIN [Nov 2015 Returns] as n on c.SKU != n.SKU " & _
        "SET c.SKU = n.SKU, c.[Item Description] = n.[Item Description], c.[Nov 2015 FIN YTD TY % Returns] = n.[Nov 2015 FIN YTD TY % Returns]"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL 'code' I'm also going to select it as answer cause you did help me solve what I needed to do :)

Comment: Heartless, put this in a SQL fiddle and i'll have a look. note that when updating, you need to use this syntax: update TABLE SET field=x FROM TABLE...JOIN... WHERE... (in case you want to use a join in an update...)

Comment: Hey AlexT82, Apologies for responding now only... I was able to fix what I had a problem with... I just split the update with an insert as well, because there was SKU that got added later on with the newer reports that had greater as SKU numbers... However, your advise worked great, there is going to be pivot charts made, I have two access files now lol cause the one is working still and the other is for pivot charts... I was finally also able to up vote your answer :D